# Reload only main page content on link click

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

So i'm trying to do an effect similar to this http://www.hffm.co.uk/

When you click on another page the entire page Does NOT reload just the main content in the center But the link at in the navigation does

I.e http://www.hffm.co.uk/contact after contact page is clicked

What i want to know is how is this done?  I don't like using jquery but can convert it if you can only explain it that way. I figure it's AJAX related but can't be sure. Does this kind of loading have a name?

I need to know what to search so i can find it google to figure it out myself but i have no idea where to go looking.

Comment: It's called a single page application.

Comment: All you have to do is get the page content which does not change from the server via AJAX (using JavaScript). Changing the URL is achieved by pushing to the browser history: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page?rq=1

Comment: @ItsGreg I mean how about page transition http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible with ajax.
it's call asynchronous load. Im not realy skilled to explain so here is a link
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp
I hope it helped